# Redis eviction policy clarification

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I'm new to Redis and could not find any information on that online so asking it here.
Suppose I have multiple database Redis cluster and I'm using **LRU/LFU** eviction policy.

I wonder if Redis eviction policy is **database** based? What I mean is, suppose I'm trying to insert a new item to **DB 0** and I ran out of memory, will Redis evict items in **DB 0** and complete the insertion? Or will it evict an item in any database based on the eviction policy?

I would expect that the eviction will be in the same virtual database.
In case the eviction policy is across different databases, what will happen if I reach the size limit of the database? Will it evict the keys inside that **DB** based on the eviction policy or the inserts will just fail?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple test to see it;

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "0"
127.0.0.1:6379> select 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "0"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> config set maxmemory 100mb
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "104857600"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> select 0
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "104857600"
127.0.0.1:6379> select 2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "104857600"
127.0.0.1:6379[2]>
```

As you can see when you set maxmemory to the `database 0`, also other databases have the same `maxmemory` value. They all share the same resource(memory), when you run `INFO MEMORY` in any database they will print the same values (didn't share it -huge- but you can test).

I think it is not database specific, they are just virtually separated. You don't run out of memory in only one database but all databases.

Comment: Correct - all logical databases share all configuration settings (e.g maxmemory, save, ...) - put differently, the configuration is global